# How to remove `//<![CDATA[` and end `//]]>` with javascript from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cdata

How to remove `//<![CDATA[` and end `//]]>` with javascript from string?

```
var title = "<![CDATA[A Survey of Applications of Identity-Based Cryptography in Mobile Ad-Hoc Networks]]>" ;
```

needs to become

```
var title = "A Survey of Applications of Identity-Based Cryptography in Mobile Ad-Hoc Networks";
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `String.prototype.replace` method, like:

```
title = title.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", "");
```

This will replace each target substring with nothing. Note that this will only replace the first occurrence of each, and would require a regular expression if you want to remove all matches.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: How will it work if your string has multiple `<![CDATA[` ?

Comment: This trivial answer is wrong, because you can encode the literal string "<![CDATA[" inside a <![CDATA[ structure itself - the only way to properly "remove" the *outside* <![CDATA[ string is to remove the wrappers one-at-a-time from left to right, taking care NOT to remove any **encoded** "<![CDATA[" constructs that are meant to be inside there...  Specifically - the thing you want to DECODE originally had THIS done to it in order to first ENCODE it:  .replaceAll(']]>',']]]]><![CDATA[>');

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to do this with a regex.  Maybe something like this?:

```
var myString = "<![CDATA[A Survey of Applications of Identity-Based Cryptography in Mobile Ad-Hoc Networks]]>";
var myRegexp = /<!\[CDATA\[(.*)]]>/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: I would just get the array value in a single line: `var match = myRegexp.exec(myString)[1];`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this wider way to remove leading and trailing CDATA stuff :

```
title.trim().replace(/^(\/\/\s*)?<!\[CDATA\[|(\/\/\s*)?\]\]>$/g, '')
```

It will also work if CDATA header and footer are commented.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expresion `/^(<!\[CDATA\[)|(]]>)$/gm` worked for me without looping.

Answer (score 0):

You must perform the OPPOSITE of what was originally done to the string to ENCODE it, which was this:-

```
mystr='<!CDATA[' + mystr.replaceAll(']]>',']]]]><![CDATA[>') + ']]>'
```

All the other answers on this page that suggest "replace" without using a loop are wrong.

Comment: FYI: CDATA encoding requires that replaceAll step to "escape" any potential "]]>" sequence that might be inside the string you want to encode.