# Google sheet xml import how to remove <![CDATA[TEXT]]> tags?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import

I use this script to fetch XML into google sheet:

```
function XML() {
  const url = 'xml.url'
  const request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  const html = request.getContentText()

  const names = html.match(/<id>(.*?)<\/id>/g)
    .map(name => /<id>(.*?)<\/id>/g.exec(name)[1])

  const percentage = html.match(/<price>(.*?)<\/price>/g)
    .map(p => /<price>(.*?)<\/price>/g.exec(p)[1])

  const title = html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/g)
    .map(name => /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/g.exec(name)[1])

  const man = html.match(/<manufacturer>(.*?)<\/manufacturer>/g)
    .map(man => /<manufacturer>(.*?)<\/manufacturer>/g.exec(man)[1])
    
  const kat = html.match(/<short_description>(.*?)<\/short_description>/g)
    .map(kat => /<short_description>(.*?)<\/short_description>/g.exec(kat)[1])    
  const results = []

  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    results.push([names[i], percentage[i], title[i], man[i], kat[i]])
  }

  return results
```

But i get this  result ... `<![CDATA[TEXT]]>`

How to fix the code to get only 'TEXT' without tags

> `"<![CDATA[]]>"`

?

Comment: Welcome. "But i get this result" - what result is that?  Please Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My apologise i had to post it like code because dissapear after post it here :D...i think is fixed now...

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var xmlStuff = "<![CDATA[TEXT]]>"
  var results = xmlStuff.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", "");
  console.log(results)
}
```

**OR**

`var results = xmlStuff.trim().replace(/^(\/\/\s*)?<!\[CDATA\[|(\/\/\s*)?\]\]>$/g, '')`

**OR**

```
var myRegexp = /<!\[CDATA\[(.*)]]>/;
var results = myRegexp.exec(xmlStuff);
console.log(results[1])
```

---

Applying the recommended answer for [How to remove `//<![CDATA[` and end `//]]>` with javascript from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10934822/1330560)